# What does the phrase “a bar for nothing” mean?

Tags: terminology, jazz

I’ve heard this phrase most commonly used when counting off a song in a jazz context. The MD will say “I’ll give you a bar for nothing” and then count off the song.

What does it mean?

Comment: What does "The MD" refer to in Jazz performance?  Is it a name for a role in the band?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Musical Director. Generally the piano/keyboard player, but I've been in bands where MD is the drummer. Not always jazz bands, could be any style, any size.

Comment: @Tim Thanks.  But in classical group (chamber or orchestra), I have never heard "MD" used colloquially (like in rehearsal, or in referring to the conductor in conversations), even though the term "musical director" / "artistic director" is meaningful as a job title.  Isn't it always maestro / conductor / dirigent in the classical music world?  Or am I wrong?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - I would imagine that the conductor of an *orchestra* would never use the phrase. It's used more by ensembles, jazz, etc.

Comment: As opposed to giving ... Measure For Measure   :-)

Comment: @Tim in fact plenty of conductors of ensembles of any size and any stature will use "bar" for "measure."   Granted the more professional groups don't need or want free beats before the actual downbeat.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - it will depend a lot on which version of a piece (jazz in particular) they're going to play. My last jazz quartet could (and did) play some classic tunes in many different ways, at many different tempos. So, just an upbeat would have been useless. Yes, bar = measure. But the phrase is generally 'bar for nothing' - not meaning the drinks are free...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that a full bar will be counted before starting to play. The "for nothing" means the musicians don't have to play during that bar; thus, it's a bar "given for free."

The phrase can use any number: "two bars for nothing", "three bars for nothing", .... It's just the total number of bars to be counted ahead of the start of the song.

A definition of the phrase can be found at the [South Bay Philharmonic](https://www.southbayphilharmonic.org/glossary/) website:

> **"Bar for nothing"** (phrase)
> Typically the conductor will give one or two preparatory beats before the music begins. The phrase "bar for nothing" (or "measure for nothing") indicates the conductor will show one entire measure before the music starts. (The preparatory measure may include a pickup.)

Another definition comes from [Uketropolis: "How To Start A Song Right!"](https://www.uketropolis.com/blog/pedagogy-corner-how-to-start-a-song-right)

> So, this brings us to one last thing called a "bar for nothing."  A "bar for nothing" is when you count one extra measure just to give everyone more time to tune into your tempo, especially when there's a pickup.  So, adding a "bar for nothing" is a good idea on a piece like It Had to Be You and it would sound like this: "1, 2, 3, 4, 1, It had to be you."  A bar for nothing on Oh Susanna would sound like this: "1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, Oh I come from Alabama."  The bar for nothing is often done in cut-time like this: 1--, 2--, 1, 2, 3.

There is a seeming discrepancy between the two definitions in regard to whether the "bar for nothing" does or does not include an anacrusis. Here I can only rely on experience, which is that the "bar for nothing" includes the anacrusis if it's on the "and" of the final beat; otherwise, the "bar for nothing" is always a complete bar plus additional counts for the anacrusis bar.

There is also the phrase "beats for nothing", indicating a single, incomplete bar will be counted.

Comment: Also “for free” and just “free”. Also sometimes the number of beats or metronome click is given instead of a number of bars. So “three free” could be three clicks of the metronome without playing and then start on the fourth click.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The "free" in this case means "you don't have to work for it"; i.e., you don't have to play. "You can have this bar for free, but after that you've got to work."

Comment: Yeah, I know. Did you mean to address your comment to me?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, but it seems I misunderstood your original comment.

Comment: I was just adding that “for free” is sometimes said or written instead of “nothing” and sometimes it’s beats or “clicks” instead of bars. For example, films scores would have something like “8 free” at the top of the first bar of a cue to indicate that the ensemble will hear 8 clicks of the click track before the first beat of the cue. This terminology has bled into non-film situations sometimes, but not often. I’m the only upvote on this answer BTW. Just amplifying, not correcting.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks. Very clear.

Comment: I always assumed that ‘for nothing‘ indicates that that bar is _not_ in the written music, but is being added to it.  (I.e. you get one bar ‘for free’, and _then_ you start playing as written.)

Comment: Personally, when leading a group I would maybe not say "three free" - it's easy to mishear as any number of things, wasting time inevitably with "wait, how many measures", "start from measure 33", or similar miscommunications. That's an advantage I've long noted of "for nothing" instead of "for free"!

Answer (score -4):

Just about what it says - instead of merely counting the 'phantom' bar before the start - or the start of the bar containing the anacrucis, there'll be another, extra bar counted in, prior to that. Thus, 1, 2, 1234 would be an example, the 1, 2 being the 'bar for nothing', rather than simply counting the 1234.

Works best where a song has an anacrucis of more than the last beat, as it gives the musos a chance to lock in to the tempo more easily.

EDIT: I'm working from the premise that every number will have one bar count in, regardless, so 'for nothing' makes no sense. Adding a preceding bar prior 'for nothing' actually does!

RE-EDIT. Just had a thought from a former band leader: In a *recording* situation, there's a count of one bar, then silence for the ensuing bar, then the music starts. To ensure the count isn't recorded.  That would be the 'bar for nothing'. Maybe not so important these days, but in the days of tape, etc, saves some editing.

RE-RE-EDIT: another band leader reckons that often he gives **two** 'bars for nothing' - 1, 2, 1234. Which probably makes more sense than anything!

Comment: The "1234" is the "bar for nothing". The example given here would be "two bars for nothing".

Comment: I'm going to disagree. There needs to be a count in, so that's something. Can't just go 'ready, steady, go'! So the bar prior would be the bar for nothing. It's what we've called it in all my 60-odd years playing in bands.

Comment: I think it depends heavily on context. An orchestra won't get a count in bar by default, in fact it can be very confusing when you DO get one when you're not expecting it. In that case the conductor would often say 'I'll give you a bar of nothing' to be clear, and that bar would be the one leading up to the first played bar. In band playing, yeah I get you, though I've not heard it explicitly called a bar of nothing, just 2 bars in or similar. Usually it's just clear from the context when something needs to be described as a bar of nothing!

Comment: @OwenM - yes, I really wouldn't expect the conductor of an orchestra to use a phrase like 'bar for nothing'. Mostly they'll get an upbeat to bring them in. Often thought about 4 players needing 1 or 2 bars count in, but  100 piece orchestra only needing beat 4! Generally used with bands.

Comment: @Tim, yes but what I mean is a conductor WILL, relatively frequently, give us a bar of nothing, when rehearsing, and will describe it in exactly those words to us. And in such a case it will be the bar directly preceding the first written bar :) It's true it will normally only need a downbeat, we usually don't need a tempo set because we have a conductor. But when sight reading slightly more finicky stuff the bar of nothing thing will come up semi frequently!

Comment: Maybe this is a US vs UK English thing: What does "Just about what it says" mean here?

Comment: Separate comment: Regarding "There needs to be a count in...", try telling that to any band or orchestra director. At the pro level, you're happy to get the upswing of the baton. Regarding "I really wouldn't expect the conductor of an orchestra to use a phrase like 'bar for nothing'." I've gotten this or similar phrasing many times in conducted large "classical" ensembles, but **in rehearsal**, not at the show.

Comment: My first comment is that the whole “orchestra only gets an upbeat” is irrelevant here because that has been hashed over many times here in other questions and this question is asked in a jazz context. My second is that 1, 2, 1234 (or 1234, 2234) is two for nothing, not one for nothing unless there is a pickup bar. Finally although we are all used to it and accept 1, 2, 1234, shouldn’t it be 1, 3, 1234 instead? A drummer friend in a big band actually does that.

Comment: @ToddWilcox exactly, for the show the conductors up-baton compared to down-baton is all thats needed to initiate the tempo of the piece. In rehearsal the conductor being clear that they are giving a 'a bar of nothing' before the first written measure is relatively common and necessary, while the piece is settling in. Otherwise the musicians would start counting bars from the first downbeat and could easily end up a bar off.